# Turn Off loopback audio in meetings

Tags: 20.04, sound, microphone, headphones

Me and other friends who use ubuntu noticed an annoying problem, when we are in a meeting (meet, slack, teams, etc.) if someone listens to any audio or video on the computer, this sound is sent through the person's phone, so everyone can hear what the person is listening to, I've researched a lot about it and I can't find anything that allows me to turn off this audio feedback, I've used alsamixer i tried to disable or reduce the volume of several options including the PCM that was recommended in another topic but this PCM without volume i couldn't hear anything and use pavucontrol i also tried to change the volumes and mute some and it didn't work, in the configuration tab I selected "Analog duplex stereo", and I haven't found any option to turn this problem off, we all use headphones with microphones that have the P3 connector.
4 friends and I are using ubuntu 20.04 and everyone has the same problem

Answer (score 0):

In **pavucontrol**, "input devices " tab:
Change display to "all input devices" and check
monitor is not the default input:
this is activated by  buttons   near each input.

You may also find a "loopback" setting in alsamixer  depending your hardware:
scroll to the right in the alsamixer terminal.

Comment: did not work, and performing this operation, the default ubuntu microphone is not recognized [Imagem](http://i.imgur.com/EHCqZ49.png)

Comment: one thing I noticed is that this feedback only happens on the phone with P3 connector, if you use a usb phone, this feedback does not occur